# group of columns in awk

Tags: awk

The following awk statement is working as expected.

```
awk '{print $1, $2, $3}' test.txt
```

But how do I say that I need all the columns after the second column?

```
awk '{print $1, $2, $3 to $NF}' test.txt
```

I need all columns from third column till end of that line. There can be 2 to 10 columns and all are considered as a part of the last column.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if you just want `$3-$NF` fields, standard way would be loop (`for/while`)

but for your requirement, you could:

```
awk '{$1=$2="";}sub("^ *","")'
```

for example:

```
kent$  seq -s' ' 10|awk '{$1=$2="";}sub("^ *","")' 
3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10
```

if you want to "group" 100 fields into 3 groups: 1,2, 3-100:

```
awk '{x=$0;sub($1FS$2,"",x);gsub(FS,"",x);print $1,$2,x}'
```

same example:

```
kent$  seq -s' ' 10|awk '{x=$0;sub($1FS$2,"",x);gsub(FS,"",x);print $1,$2,x}'    
1 2 345678910
```

hope it is what you want.

Answer (score 1):

The intuitive way.

`awk  'BEGIN{ORS=""} {for(i=3; i<=NF; i++) if(i != NF){print $i " "} else {print $i "\n"}}' test.txt`

Answer (score 0):

Some more:

```
awk '{$1=$2=x; $0=$0; $1=$1}1' file

awk '{$1=$1; sub($1 FS $2 FS,x)}1' file
```

To keep spacing in tact:

```
awk 'sub($1 "[ \t]*" $2 "[ \t]*",x)' file
```